# Creating multiple images using multiple URLs

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to grab posts and images from Reddit's API. I am able to get the titles of each post and display them on my web page and I can also get the URL's with no issue. My problem is when I want to create images for each URL I don't know how to go about it. Do I need to create a new  element for each post or can I use the current "reddit-image" element? Currently it's only displaying the image for the latest post.

```
//jshint esversion:6
const apiUrl = "https://www.reddit.com/r/gaming.json";

async function getData (){
  const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
  const data = await response.json();
  const posts = data.data.children;
 
  posts.forEach( function(post){
    
const redditTitle = document.getElementById("reddit-title");
const redditContainer = document.getElementById("reddit-container");
const redditImage = document.getElementById("reddit-image");    

const urlString = post.data.url;
    
   
      var lastFourLetters = urlString.substring(urlString.length -4);
      var lastFiveLetters = urlString.substring(urlString.length -5);


    
    

      if(lastFourLetters ==".jpg" || lastFiveLetters ==".jpeg"){
        if(post.data.thumbnail !="self"){
          redditContainer.innerHTML +=post.data.title + "<br>";
        redditImage.src=urlString;
      }

    }
  });
    
  
  
}

getData();
```

Comment: The problem could be the fact that you are using IDs inside of a loop. The problem with using IDs inside of a loop is the fact that you are probably overriding the last element since you can't reuse IDs. I would post a basic version of the HTML where the posts will be going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
//jshint esversion:6
const apiUrl = "https://www.reddit.com/r/gaming.json";

async function getData (){
  const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
  const data = await response.json();
  const posts = data.data.children;
 
  posts.forEach( function(post){
    
const redditTitle = document.getElementById("reddit-title");
const redditContainer = document.getElementById("reddit-container");
const redditImage = document.getElementById("reddit-image");    

const urlString = post.data.url;
    
   
      var lastFourLetters = urlString.substring(urlString.length -4);
      var lastFiveLetters = urlString.substring(urlString.length -5);


    
    

      if(lastFourLetters ==".jpg" || lastFiveLetters ==".jpeg"){
        if(post.data.thumbnail !="self"){
          redditContainer.innerHTML +=post.data.title + "<br>";
           var img = document.createElement('img'); 
            img.src =urlString; 
            redditContainer .appendChild(img); 
      }

    }
  });
    
  
  
}

getData();
```